# Display NSViewController's view as NSView's (NSScrollView) subview

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift3, nsview, nsviewcontroller

I have different `NSViewController`s that have multiple fields. One has NSDatePicker,
another has NSTextField and so on.

Example: 
[image: CustomViewController]

The idea is to display these in NSScrollView when I click on particular buttons.

[image: ScrollViewWithViews]

So I came up with the next solution:

My main `ViewController` class has a variable **viewControlers: [`ViewController`]** that holds all the custom `ViewController`s (with different inputs). When I click on button I initialize certain `ViewController`, and then add it's view to the scroll view.

Examle:

```
let dmyVC = storyBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "DayMonthYearVC") as! DayMonthYearSelectVC
self.viewControlers.append(dmyVC) //add new vc to the array 
scrollView.addSubview(dmyVC.view) //add this VC’s view to a scroll view
```

I added `NSButton` that triggers “close()” function to every custom `ViewController`s with inputs. Then on those `ViewController`s in the “close” function I do:

```
self.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

However it only removes a `ViewController`’s view from the scrollView, but the `ViewController` itself is not deallocated and it remains in the **viewControlers** array (variable inside mainViewController)

I was thinking of creating delegates, and call a delegate method every time when close button on one of those views is pressed. In this case I simply need to have an array of delegates (for every custom `ViewController`) [parallel to the array that holds references to all those `ViewController`s that were created].

---

*Now I think, is there a common way of dealing with a situation when you want to present `ViewController`s’ views inside another view, or everyone does it in a way they like better?*

Comment: Not related the question but `scrollView.addSubview(dmyVC.view)` isn't how you add a view to a scroll view.

Comment: scrollView is just an NSView that later becomes a documentView of ScrollView ( mainScrollView.documentView = scrollView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution A: a delegate. All view controllers can have the same delegate, the main view controller. The closing view controller is a parameter of the delegate method.

Solution B: a custom notification. The main view controller observes the notification. The closing view controller posts the notification and is the object of the notification.

Comment: Thanks, the idea of a closing view controller as a parameter of the delegate method is much better than having an array of delegates.